# Hey I am using 2 4N35 Optocoupler from Visha can I replace them with a single ILD615 from Vishay?

Tags: power, pcb, analog, schematics, opto-isolator

[image]I went through both datasheets and i think it should work.

Basically I am asking if the dual channel version of 4N35 is the 8 dip ILD615.

Thanks.
edit:
I have added the picture. my circuit is like the link.  when vin is postive i need GPIO at Vout to be 1 (High) and otherwise Vout 0 (Low)

Comment: In 4N35, you have access to base of the transistor. In ILD615, you don't. Most likely you won't be needing the base connection and you can go with dual channel one. However you should post the exact circuit to get a correct response.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack  thanks  Actually my circuit is very basic i got HIGH connected to the Emmiter and on the Collector its 10K resistor to the ground.   Whenever there is positive voltage on the diode led of the optocoupler the signal will go from 0 to 1 logic.

I think i shuld be fine using the ILD615

Comment: You might be confused here. You might be connecting HIGH to collector and 10K pull down to Emitter. Please verify.

Comment: Hey, show the proper circuit and describe it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way of using opto-coupler:

[image: PC817]

This is PC817 and lacks a base connection. Most likely you also don't need it. This circuit will generate a HIGH Output when there is a HIGH Input.

In this case, you can use ILD615 if you need a dual channel. Connections will be similar. You don't to worry about base connection.

[image: ILD]

Compare the two images and you will know how to connect everything.